# How to Force WWW. in Domain With WordPress MU Domain Mapping Plugin?

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, redirect, urls, domain-mapping

I created a thread ([How to make www. and no www. Go to same site, for all sites?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-www-and-no-www-go-to-same-site-for-all-sites)) in the support forums for the WordPress plugin: [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

Everything is fine and dandy. I have a base domain, along with several other domains. I have added all of the domains successfully.

However, I get `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` to work, but they're separate URL structures. I need `domain.com` to redirect to `www.domain.com`, for each of the mapped domains, much like my base domain does.

How can I achieve non-www domains to redirect to www domains for each of my mapped domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered from this [thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-mu-domain-mapping-non-www-mapped-domians-erroring-out?replies=10#post-1715971).

**Summary:**

The .htaccess redirect for www/non-www...

```
# www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.subdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put it ABOVE your WordPress rules on domain.com. Should work.

**Example:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# DOMAIN #1 - Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# DOMAIN #2 - Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# DOMAIN #3 ... ETC - Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain3.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It would be nice if someone could explain how to force a trailing slash to each of my domains as well (if not present).

Comment: WP MU Domain Mapping 0.5.4.3 does this, just add two domains for a subsite and set the www one to have priority, and it redirects perfectly. The trailing slash should be googlable, and you have an example in the pasted .htaccess.